# Best way to make cross-platform locale-independent string code in C++ without using ILU

Tags: c++, string, cross-platform, locale

Background (through it's not that important for the scope of problem): I am working on game framework in C++ based on SDL that will be compiled on different platforms (Win/Lin/Mac/iOS/Android/etc.) and I need good, cross-platform way to store locale-dependent string which is not so bloated like ICU library is

The wchar_t is not an option here, because of it's platform dependence. You can't (for example) save a game on Linux (wchar_t is 4 bytes long) and then load in on Windows (because wchar_t is 2 bytes long).

So, my idea is to make universal character string (UCS-2) as standard inside my framework and games made atop of it. I want to do simple typedef in core header:

```
typedef unsigned short uchar
typedef std::basic_string<uchar> ustring
```

The problem is that many underlying libraries uses different string encoding. So I need couple of functions:

```
std::string UStrToAscii(const ustring & str);
ustring AsciiToUStr(const char * str);

std::string UStrToUtf8(const ustring & str);
ustring Utf8ToUStr(const char * str);

std::wstring UStrToWide(const ustring & str);
ustring WideToUStr(const wchar_t * str);

// etc.
```

I am returning STL object, because I don't need to worry about their lifetime and time/memory cost is pretty small.

Questions:

- Is it "right track" to do locale/platform independent strings? Or perhaps there is much easier solution I missed on Google?
- How should I define string in code (for example to be used in Logger)?

My idea is to use macro like this:

```
#define _U(str) WideToUStr(L##str)

// Then in code:
_U("Hello World zażółć gęślą jaźń"); // some polish special chars
```

But I don't know if it's a right track (is it cross-platform? Could it be completed easier?)

- Second problem: it's clear that I cannot rely on sprintf. My idea is to write my own print formatted text function, but perhaps there is some easier way?

Ah, and I don't want to use UTF-8 as native format in my framework - it's way too compilcated to do simple task on strings (like substrings, get char from index, etc - you have to traverse entire string and make sure that the byte at picked index is actually a char, not an entity of other char, etc.)

**EDIT**

To be clear, the not-UTF8 rule is not my deal-breaker, it's merely discouraged because of it's limitations. But if the only right way to do is is by UTF-8 (pros strongly beats cons), then it's acceptable as answer

Comment: Why is UTF-8 too complicated for substrings and get char from index?  Just use *byte* indices, not *character* indices, and make sure you never return a pointer into the middle of a multibyte character.  If you haven't read [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/), I highly recommend giving that a thorough read-through.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield there is no easy way in UTF-8 to point for example 256-st character without traversing entire string, or substituting one character with one longer without (sometimes needed) very costly (on mobile platforms) string reallocation

Comment: UCS-2 is deprecated since 2 bytes are not enough to encode all the unicode characters. It has been replaced by UTF-16 which uses 2 or 4 bytes per characters, has none of the benefits of UTF-8 (like compatibility with ascii), and has the additional problem of endianess. Especially the endianness problem is reason enough to never touch UCS-2/UTF-16

Comment: @youdontneedtothankme I want a fixed-size encoding. UCS-2 will *always* give me 2 bytes per character. Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 does not have such luxury. And I don't need to encode all the unicode characters :)

Comment: @PiotrK: How often do you need to know what the 256th *character* is in a string?  I'm being serious.  Almost any operation I can think of, except possibly for font rendering, doesn't care about the character count, only the byte count.  It's true that 1-for-1 character replacements aren't necessarily 1-for-1 byte replacements and could entail reallocations, but UCS-2/UTF-16 also has that problem (for example, when the German ß is capitalized, it's replaced by the two characters SS, which increases the string length by 1).